# How to store array in firestore database using Android?

Tags: android, arrays, list, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create an firestore model like below:

```
attendance_log (root collection)
|
|--- 001 (document ID)
|    |
|    |--- date : 20190310
|    |--- time : 1025
|    |--- subject : "Android Programming"
|    |--- present : {"MCA01", "MCA03", "MCA04"}
|    |--- absent : {"MCA02, "MCA05"}
```

I could store date, time and subject by passing the value in a Map as below :

```
Map<String, Object> attend = new HashMap<>();
attend.put("date", d) ;
attend.put("time", t) ;
attend.put("subject", subject) ;

db.collection("attendance_log")
    .document(docID)
    .set(attend)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid){
            Toast.makeText(TakeAttendance.this,"Attendance added sucessfully" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.cdlayout) ,"Something went wrong!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

But passing the array generates the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not serialize object. Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead
```

Comment: seriously? --->>>> "Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead"

Comment: what is inside your subject variable? It should be Object not array[]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in your error - you need to read your error and check what does it say - in your case, you will see that Arrays are not supported and you need to send list instead.

You can use `Arrays.asList(yourArray)` to convert your array and send it to your database.

Change this line:

`attend.put("subject", subject) ;`

To This line:

```
attend.put("subject", Arrays.asList(subject)) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to worry you are very near to the correct code. In firestore you can store array String[] instead you have to use List:

```
     //convert array to arraylist
      ArrayList<String> subjectsArrayList = getListOfSubjects(subjects);
      Map<String, Object> attend = new HashMap<>();
      attend.put("date", d) ;
      attend.put("time", t) ;
      attend.put("subject", subject) ;

      hashMap.put("subjects", subjectsArrayList);
      db.collection("attendance_log")
                .document(docId)
                .update(attend)
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    //done
                });
```

Here is `getListOfSubjects` method

```
  public ArrayList<String> getListOfSubjects(String[] subjects){
        List<String> subjectsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) {
            subjectsArrayList.add(subjects[i]);
        }
        return (ArrayList<String>) subjectsArrayList;
    }
```

Hope this will help you.